# Rails url helpers in subdomains - remove the subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

A user on my site can have a subdomain.  So for example, their page url is

```
name.example.com
```

Logged in users are able to view more user information so on the user's show page, I have a link that is generated with the following code:

```
user_url(@user, :subdomain => false)
```

This link should generate the following url (where @user has an ID of 19)

```
example.com/users/19
```

When I hover over the link, all looks good (i.e., in the bottom of the browser window, both Safari and FF show the link correctly.)

Problem is when I click the link, the site raises a 404 and the url is:

```
example.com/users/19
```

Anyone know what happened to the slash between com and users and how do I get it back?

BTW, Rails 3.2 and everything works in development.  This issue only arises in production.

Comment: couple of quick qs - have you tried rake routes to see what all your route options are and make sure they all look right?

Comment: Do you have some kind of 'base url' setting in `config/production.rb`?

Comment: can you post your routes or how you are generating the subdomain in the first place?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First suggestion was using path helper instead of user helper, but editing that as I don't think that helps.

Have you tried root_url(:host => request.domain) to lose the subdomain, instead of your approach?  I got that from here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2025

Comment: request.domain is what I was looking for. +1