# Testing subdomains in controller specs in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I've successfully got my **controller specs** working with subdomains by using a before filter like so

```
before do 
    request.host = "an_account.example.com"
end
```

When a user tries to access a subdomain they are not part of, they are logged out and sent back to devise's sign in action which ISNT under a subdomain i.e.

www.example.com/users/sign_in

Everything works fine in the browser, sneaky users are redirected are barred from entering unrelated subdomains and instead redirected to the sign in form.

However my controller specs are failing with

> "Expected response to be a redirect to
>   http://example.com/users/sign_in but was a redirect to
>   http://an_account.example.com/users/sign_in"

Can anyone help on this?

Here is the before_filter which authorizes users

```
def authorize_account_subdomain!
    if current_account.subdomain != request.subdomain
      sign_out
      flash[:warning] = t('errors.unauthorized')
      redirect_to new_user_session_url(:subdomain => false)
    end
  end
```

and the test

```
context 'when signed_in' do
    let(:user)      { create(:user_with_account) }
    let(:proposal)  { create(:proposal, :account => user.account) }
    let(:subdomain) { user.account.subdomain }

    before do
      sign_in user
    end

    context "when accessing other subdomain" do

      before do 
        other_subdomain = "other_subdomain"
        @request.host = "#{other_subdomain}.example.com"
      end

      it "can not access show action" do
        post :show, :id => 1
        access_denied!
      end
   end
end


#test helper

def access_denied!
    response.should redirect_to new_user_session_url(:subdomain => false)
    flash[:warning].should == I18n.t('errors.unauthorized')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

When I look at this I see the query is correct, i.e. /users/sign_in is the same in both cases. So that tells me that its the :subdomain => false in your url helper.

See this answer for more clarification

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15624241/793330